# How to enforce Active Directory password complexity

Tags: powershell, active-directory

As per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements), using PowerShell or cmd, I want to force a user to have specific password requirements. I tried editing a config file in `secedit`.

```
secedit /export /cfg c:\secpol.cfg
$min_pass_regex = "MinimumPasswordLength = \d+"
$min_pass_length = 10
$min_pass_requirement = "MinimumPasswordLength = $($min_pass_length)"

(gc C:\secpol.cfg).replace("RequireLogonToChangePassword = 0", "RequireLogonToChangePassword = 1") | Out-File C:\secpol.cfg
(gc C:\secpol.cfg).replace("PasswordComplexity = 0", "PasswordComplexity = 1") | Out-File C:\secpol.cfg
(gc C:\secpol.cfg) -replace $min_pass_regex, $min_pass_requirement | Out-File C:\secpol.cfg
cat C:\secpol.cfg
secedit /configure /db c:\windows\security\local.sdb /cfg c:\secpol.cfg /areas SECURITYPOLICY
```

However, the user gets no warning to create a more secure password, even after restarting. How can I enforce this policy?

Comment: Why not use GPO?

Comment: @Adam I need a way to do this programmatically. These aren't servers but user devices.

Comment: @user1222324562 gotcha. Checkout the answer I just gave. I think the  one article will be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think you may want to look at `Set-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy`. Read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-addefaultdomainpasswordpolicy?view=win10-ps